# My Discord.py bot is giving inconsistent output

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This bot's job is to check when someone joins rank 1 and then say a message in a staff channel of there Discord and there ign. People in the channel can use !comment <# many messages back> to leave a comment about the member. For some reason on the server it works perfectly but the after a few days of running sometimes it will miss a comment. Please get back to me. The Bot is hosted with heroku.

```
import discord, os, time
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = discord.Client()

msg = None
targetGuild = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
msgList = []

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global channel
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
        if guild.name == targetGuild:
            print(f"RoleCheck has connected to {guild.name}")
            channel = guild.get_channel(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    newRole = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
    if newRole.name == "1":
        global msg
        msg = await channel.send(f"IGN:{after.nick} \nDiscord:{after.name}")
        print(f"IGN:{after.nick} \nDiscord:{after.name}")
        msgList.append(msg)
        print(msgList)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global msg, msgList
    if message.content.startswith("!comment"):
        print("TEST")
        if message.content[9].isnumeric() and not message.content[10].isnumeric():
            print("1")
            msg = msgList[int("-"+message.content[9])]
            _content = msg.content + '\n' + message.author.name + ': ' + message.content[11:]
            await msg.edit(content=_content)
        elif message.content[10].isnumeric():
            print("2")
            await channel.send("Role check only supports single digit numbers")
        else:
            print("3")
            _content = msg.content + '\n' + message.author.name + ': ' + message.content[9:]
            await msg.edit(content=_content)

    elif message.content.startswith("!rolecheckhelp"):
        await channel.send("---RoleCheck--- \n!comment - will add a comment on the last message with whatever you write after\n !help = will show the help screen\n Made with python and the discord.py API by xxxxxxxxxx")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Heroku restarts your dyno every 24 hours, meaning your bot is not online 24/7 to catch all the comments,  so it's bound to miss a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should solve your issue.  As stated by Jawad in a comment, heroku restarts every 24 hours.  To fix this, you'd need to create a system that persists your code.  I've done this below using the python `_pickle` library to store your list on update as a physical file.  This file is also read and loaded `on_ready` when your bot is restarted.

For ease of control, I've also added an administrative command that only fires if the person using it has admin rights on your server that clears the `msgList` completely.

```python
import _pickle as pickle
import discord, os, time
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = discord.Client()

msg = None
targetGuild = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
msgList = []

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global channel, msgList
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
        if guild.name == targetGuild:
            print(f"RoleCheck has connected to {guild.name}")
            channel = guild.get_channel(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

    # Open the messages.p cache and read contents after restart
    with open("./messages.p", 'r') as pfile:
        msgList = pickle.load(pfile)    

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    newRole = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
    if newRole.name == "1":
        global msg, msgList

        # Open the messages.p cache and read contents prior to updating
        with open("./messages.p", 'r') as pfile:
            msgList = pickle.load(pfile)
        
        msg = await channel.send(f"IGN:{after.nick} \nDiscord:{after.name}")
        print(f"IGN:{after.nick} \nDiscord:{after.name}")
        msgList.append(msg)
        print(msgList)

        # Open messages.p cache and overwrite it with new content after update
        with open("./messages.p", 'w') as pfile:
            pickle.dump(msgList, pfile)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global msg, msgList
    if message.content.startswith("!comment"):
        print("TEST")
        if message.content[9].isnumeric() and not message.content[10].isnumeric():
            print("1")
            msg = msgList[int("-"+message.content[9])]
            _content = msg.content + '\n' + message.author.name + ': ' + message.content[11:]
            await msg.edit(content=_content)
        elif message.content[10].isnumeric():
            print("2")
            await channel.send("Role check only supports single digit numbers")
        else:
            print("3")
            _content = msg.content + '\n' + message.author.name + ': ' + message.content[9:]
            await msg.edit(content=_content)

    elif message.content.startswith("!rolecheckhelp"):
        await channel.send("---RoleCheck--- \n!comment - will add a comment on the last message with whatever you write after\n !help = will show the help screen\n Made with python and the discord.py API by xxxxxxxxxx")

    elif message.content.lower().startswith("!purge_msg_list"):
        if message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:

            # Clear msgList and set it to [], then open messages.p cache and overwrite
            msgList = []
            with open("./messages.p", "w") as pfile:
                pfile.dump(msgList, pfile)
            await channel.send("Messages in msgList have been purged.")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I tried doing this with pickle and at first this did not work by just storing the message list, I instead stored message ID in the pickle and then got the message by ID

Comment: Ok now I have the problem of Heroku not actually saving the pickle data past resets. I use git clone <heroku git link> to clone it and the pickle file was empty. Dose heroku reset the pickle file to how it was deployed - empty?

Comment: I don't utilize heroku often enough to know how it functions, but if you're using `git clone` you might have to commit the pickle file, otherwise it'll be empty because git never received the updated file.